# Where would I change the firewall setting in this setup?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, firewall

**Question:** Is it possible to make a Windows Firewall application exception via command line or any other way?

### Why

We have a host running Windows 2016 Server with several Hyper-V VM's also running Windows 2016 Server.  One is a DHCP server and one hosts the SQL DB. Windows Active Directory has also been setup on our network.

We have 3rd party developed software that works with an SQL database. On the actual VMs it works perfectly, but on any other client computer on the network we cannot get it to communicate with the VM unless temporarily disabling ALL Windows Firewalls.

We are having issues with Windows Firewall causing some things to not be able to connect, and need to add exceptions to the firewall, **but I am not sure where to do i**t.

Additionally, knowing this will help with another client issue for a VOIP SNOM PA1 system to work. After talking to vendor support and sending them log files, they believe it's also a Windows Firewall restriction causing this issue.

Comment: There’s not enough information here to even know where to start. At the very least a diagram would help.

Answer (score 2):

### Allow executable thru Windows Firewall with Command Line

Setup a Windows Firewall rule with [NETSH](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) commands and "allow" a specific application executable inbound and/or outbound on any profile from an elevated command prompt **run as administrator** with the below syntax or something similar. Then run this as a startup script once or on every startup for workstations/servers.

I assume you will only need the inbound rule applied and will point it to the full path of the executable file you need to allow inbound connections to be accepted from but I've shown an example outbound rule too in case.

### Allow App Inbound

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="3rd Party Exe Out" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files\CoolCo\Cool3P.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

### Allow App Outbound

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="3rd Party Exe Out" dir=out action=allow program="C:\Program Files\CoolCo\Cool3P.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [NETSH](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

Comment: @Lzypenguin .... For the question regarding the 3rd party app only working when W is fully disabled, I've answered that part of the question. It sounds like the VOIP is really needed detail and maybe a bit too much info. I've provided a solution to the question with that respect though. You can also open specific ports and from specific IP addresses too. Depending on how tight you want your FW allow rule, you can get more secure than the examples I provided. If you trust the exe though to allow anything to/from it to anywhere, then perhaps these examples will suffice. Happy to further adjust.

Comment: Allowing access to a PROGRAM on both the SQL VM and the program on the end user computer (the program communicates to the SQL DB on the SQL VM, and the program is installed on both so I was able to add the program as an exception on both ends) ended up solving that. Since the program was on both machines I could point to it. But there are several other programs that wont work, and I have added them to the exception on the end user, and the programs still will not work. They are not running on the server, so I do not know where else to add them as exceptions...

Answer (score 2):

### Allow Apps thru Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

You could also go to **wf.msc** and then add a rule to tell the **Windows Firewall** to allow a specific app inbound and/or outbound on all profiles.

> ### Instructions
>
> 1. Press [image] **+**<kbd>**R**</kbd>,
>      type in **wf.msc** and then press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.
> 2. Click on **Inbound Rules** and then click on **New Rule...** to the
>      right
>
>    [image]
> 3. In the **Rule Type** options window check the **Program** option and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the **Program** options window in the **This program path** field either **browse** find or specify the full explicit path of the
>      exe of the apps file which you want to allow through the **Windows
>      Firewall** and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 5. In the **Actions** options window ensure the **Allow this connection** option is selected and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 6. In the **Profile** options window ensure that all three options of **Domain**, **Public**, and **Private** are selected and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 7. In the **Name** field type in a name for the new rule and then press <kbd>**Finish**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 8. You should now see the new rule you just created. You could then click on the **Outbound Rules** option and follow the same *steps 1 - 8* as
>      listed above for the app you need to allow outbound connections.
>
>    [image]
>
> Just follow these steps for allowing all the incoming and outgoing app rules you need and scale accordingly to prevent Windows Firewall from prompting after each reboot.

Comment: @Lzypenguin .... Obviously these example screen shots show the `Chrome.exe` app in them, but you'd simply replace those with what's applicable in your environment.

Comment: Which computer would I do this on. I have tried to do it on the computer I am working on, as well as the DHCP server. I still cannot get the program to communicate.

Comment: I was able to resolve the SQL one by adding the program to the exception rule on both end user machine as well as SQL VM. Now we have other programs that are NOT communicating with the VM servers (except to get DHCP IP address) and I cannot get them to work. I have added the program to the exception list on the end user computer, and I still cannot get it to connect.

Comment: The pastebin link is pastebin.com/P4PqKLBn  The program in question I am currently working on communicates through UDP on Port 30303 and 30304. I have added that to the firewall list.

Comment: actually I was mistaken. I must have completely turned off the firewall through group policy on accident. I was able to make it work WHEN i turn off the domain firewall completely on the SQL server.  But even after adding the program to the exception it is now not working.

Comment: @Lzypenguin I actually need this output on a pastebin command wise, `netstat -ano`, I didn't realize it is UDP. Can you also tell me if you are going across subnets any from working client to server, etc.? Or all all on the same subnet, clients, VMs, and all?

Comment: We are not going across any different subnets. The server is 192.168.1.215, and all of the rest of the devices are 192.168.1.100-200.   Ok, so you want me to send you a pastebin from the server (where the program is working) and then another from the host (where it is not working while the domain firewall is on)?

Comment: Ok, i think I must have mispoken. The SQL server firewall issue I thought was resolved is now not resolved. So we have a program running on the server which works. We are trying to run this from other computers in the network. With the DOMAIN firewall turned off on the SQL VM, it will work from other computers. With it on (even after adding the program to the list of allowable programs) it will not work. I will send you the pastbin links with descriptions in just a second.

Comment: Pastebin from the server with firewall on - pastebin.com/RfNPEHVL   - Pastebin from computer other with the server Domain Firewall turned on (Program wont connect) - pastebin.com/vVm5yacs  - Now this is the same computer with the SERVER DOMAIN firewall turned off, and the SQL program working properly pastebin.com/CVdYcP0v

Comment: I actually just realized that AFTER I turned the domain firewall off, and ran the software so it connected to the SQL server sucessfully, and then turned the domain firewall back on, the software continued to work. But if i closed the software and reopened it, it goes back to not working again, and I have to turn off the domain firewall yet again to get it to connect to the SQL DB.

Comment: @Lzypenguin The command for the pastebins need to be `netstat -ano` because otherwise no UDP output. In the answer above and the screen shot with the **Profile** be sure that all 3 of those are selected. Whereever you are disabling domain and it works, confirm this there in that rule